# Cumulative values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to use the following code to calculate the cumulative sum in Power BI:

```
cumulative = CALCULATE(SUM(test[Number]),ALL('test'),test[Date] <= MAX(test[Date]))
```

However, as you can see in the picture, the result is summing up everything and not by cumulative per date.

I did some research, and apparently, the formula is not wrong.

**[image: strong text]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
cumulative = 

VAR d = test[Date] 

RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(test[Number]),ALL('test'),test[Date] <=d)
```